# VHDL - test bench - generics

Tags: vhdl

I've been working on making a decoder that I can use in multiple instances by just changing a generic value for the size of the input/output vector. The decoder will 'sll' a single bit, a number of positions based on the integer conversion of the input. The decoder itself works fine. The problem arrises when I make a test bench and compile. Resulting in:

> Error (10482): VHDL error at DECODER.vhd(41): object "n" is used but not declared

I've added the model and test bench below:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY DECODER IS
    --GENERIC (delay : delay_length := 0 ns);
    GENERIC (n      : POSITIVE := 2);
    PORT (a :   IN      std_logic_vector(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
            x   :   OUT std_logic_vector(2**n-1 DOWNTO 0));
END ENTITY DECODER;

ARCHITECTURE dflow OF DECODER IS
     CONSTANT x_out :   BIT_VECTOR (2**n-1 DOWNTO 0) :=
                            ( 0 => '1', OTHERS => '0');
BEGIN
    x <= to_stdlogicvector(x_out sll to_integer(unsigned(a)));
END ARCHITECTURE dflow;

--test bench----------------------------------------
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY TN2 IS
END ENTITY TN2;

ARCHITECTURE IO_TN2 OF TN2 IS
    COMPONENT DECODER IS
        --GENERIC (delay : delay_length := 0 ns);
        GENERIC (n      : POSITIVE := 2);
    PORT (a :   IN      std_logic_vector(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
            x   :   OUT std_logic_vector(2**n-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT DECODER;
SIGNAL a        :   std_logic_vector (n-1 DOWNTO 0); --<-- USED BUT NOT    DECLARED
 SIGNAL x   :  std_logic_vector (2**n-1 DOWNTO 0);
 BEGIN
G1  :   DECODER
    GENERIC MAP (n => 2)
    PORT MAP (a,x);

    a <= "00", "01" AFTER 1 NS, "10" AFTER 2 NS, "11" AFTER 3 NS,
          "00" AFTER 4 NS, "0Z" AFTER 5 NS;
 END ARCHITECTURE IO_TN2;

CONFIGURATION CFG_DECODER   OF TN2 IS
    FOR IO_TN2
        FOR G1  :   DECODER 
                    USE ENTITY work.DECODER(dflow)
                    GENERIC MAP (n => 2)
                    PORT MAP (a,x);
        END FOR;
    END FOR;
END CONFIGURATION CFG_DECODER;
```

The compiler is telling me that I have not declared n, which I thought I did in the component declaration. Where should I declare it?
A second question is how can I declare multiple generics i.e
1 generic for delay_length
1 generic for n
I tried putting 2 generic statements inside the model entity but the compiler did not think that was the right thing to do.

As always many thanks for the help.
D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your component declaration is stating that there is a component called `decoder`, which (along with other properties of this component) has a generic called `n`, with a default value of `2`. At this point in analysis of the file, you have said nothing about the actual value you want to assign to `n`.

My approach would be to define a constant, prior to declaring the component:

```
constant DECODER_WIDTH : integer := 2;
```

You then use this to declare your signal:

```
SIGNAL a : std_logic_vector (DECODER_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
```

when you instantiate your `decoder`, you then also bind the `n` generic to this constant:

```
G1  :   DECODER
GENERIC MAP (n => DECODER_WIDTH)
PORT MAP (a,x);
```

If you really need to have the configuration change the value of `n`, you will have to declare the `DECODER_WIDTH` constant inside a package, which this file would then `use`, both before the `TN2` entity declaration, and before the configuration statement. If you don't need the configuration to alter the decoder size, then you can just omit the `generic map` from the configuration statement.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comments I've updated the code below with the amendments you suggested and it works well

```
--test bench for 2/4 decoder----------------------------------------
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY TN2 IS
END ENTITY TN2;

ARCHITECTURE IO_TN2 OF TN2 IS
COMPONENT DECODER IS
    --GENERIC (delay : delay_length := 0 ns);
    GENERIC (n      : POSITIVE := 2);
    PORT (a :   IN      std_logic_vector(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
            x   :   OUT std_logic_vector(2**n-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT DECODER;
CONSTANT DECODER_WIDTH : integer := 2; ---<-- ADDED constant changing this    value will alter decoder vector size
SIGNAL a : std_logic_vector (DECODER_WIDTH-1 downto 0); --< changed n to decoder_width
SIGNAL x    :  std_logic_vector (2**DECODER_WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0); --< changed n to decoder_width
BEGIN
G1  :   DECODER
    GENERIC MAP (n => DECODER_WIDTH) --< pass decoder_width to n
    PORT MAP (a,x); 
    a <= "00", "01" AFTER 1 NS, "10" AFTER 2 NS, "11" AFTER 3 NS,
          "00" AFTER 4 NS, "0Z" AFTER 5 NS;
END ARCHITECTURE IO_TN2;

CONFIGURATION CFG_DECODER   OF TN2 IS
FOR IO_TN2
    FOR G1  :   DECODER 
                    USE ENTITY work.DECODER(dflow)
                    GENERIC MAP (n => decoder_width)
                    PORT MAP (a,x);
    END FOR;
END FOR;
END CONFIGURATION CFG_DECODER;
```